# error: expected '} before else

Tags: eclipse, if-statement

I am using eclipse and I will ask a stupid question: why the error? code should be ok. I guess I'm just getting old. I just don't see the error. all the {} match. 
What the code does it sets the hemisphere for geolocation in a flight simulator, as the math should not have negative numbers.
so here goes:
O_lat is tested for zero or a positive number
if positive don't mess with it. and make quadrant = 1
else its negative so we make it positive and make the quadrant = 0

that's it.

```
int vns1, vew1, vns2, vew2;
if( O_lat >= 0 ){
     { vns1 = 1; }
     else {
         vns1 = 0;
         O_lat = O_lat * -1; }}
```

Comment: there are two opening braces after `if`

Comment: This has nothing to do with the editor or IDE, but with the syntax of the language, which you neglect to tell us.

Answer (score 2):

All the braces match, but the `else` is not where it should be for the `if`.

Remove one of the superfluous braces:

```
int vns1, vew1, vns2, vew2;
if( O_lat >= 0 ){
     vns1 = 1; 
}
else {
     vns1 = 0;
     O_lat = O_lat * -1; 
}
```

Comment: like i said "getting old"

Answer (score 1):

Just re-arrange the code a bit:

```
 int vns1, vew1, vns2, vew2;
    if( O_lat >= 0 )
           {
           { //this is unnecessary
           vns1 = 1; 
           }
         else 
           {
             vns1 = 0;
             O_lat = O_lat * -1; 
           }
           }//this is unnecessary too
```